# Docker e Pastas Compartilhadas pelo VirtualBox

Tags: docker, virtualbox

Preciso de um help, galera. Meu cenário é o seguinte:

Tenho o Windows 10 instalado no meu computador.
No Windows 10 eu instalei o Virtualbox.
No Virtualbox eu criei uma VM e instalei o Debian.
Agora, dentro do Debian, eu instalei o Docker.

No Virtualbox, eu adicionei o compartilhamento de uma pasta do Windows para que eu possa acessar pelo Debian.
Eu quero colocar os projetos que eu desenvolvo nesta pasta. Desta forma, eu não vou precisar fazer backup dos arquivos que estão no Debian.

As pastas compartilhadas entre Windows e VM Debian funcionam perfeitamente
O Docker funciona perfeitamente na minha VM Debian.
Os projetos funcionam perfeitamente, desde que não estejam dentro da pasta compartilhada.

Este é o meu problema: se eu coloco os arquivos dos projetos na pasta compartilhada, sou surpreendido por falta de acesso.
Eu já tentei alterar as permissões da pasta compartilhada para 777 (todo mundo tem acesso a tudo) mas não está funcionando.

Meu problema é falta de acesso. O docker não tem permissão para acessar a pasta compartilhada.

Como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 2):

O Windows e o Linux além de não compartilhar um sistema de arquivos, também não compartilham um sistema de gerenciamento de diretrizes de permissão.

O Linux tem seu sistema de permissões derivado do Unix, na época que a AT&T começou a projetá-lo, espaço em disco era caríssimo, portanto o sistema foi projetado para economizar cada bit do disco.  Cada arquivo terá somente 3 conjuntos de permissões: acesso a todos, ao grupo do dono e ao dono. Para se ter diretrizes de permissões mais complexas é necessário utilizar uma metodologia diferente chamada ACL que não é suportado pelo Linux nativamente, dependendo da instalação de novos pacotes. Outro problema é que o ACL não é implementado no compartilhamento que o VirtualBox disponibiliza.

Já no windows, as permissões foram levadas ao extremo. Cada arquivo pode ter permissões específicas para qualquer número de usuários distintos, grupos e para Todos. Além disso "Todos" pode ter significados diferentes: "Todos usuários autenticados"; "Todos os visitantes"; "Todos os usuários do sistema"; "Todos os usuários de rede". Para piorar, as permissões podem ter comportamentos de herança entre pastas e arquivos filhos, dentre outras possibilidades.

Quando um serviço (como o do VirtualBox) compartilha pastas do Windows no Linux ele trabalha no sentido de deixar esse abismo de diferenças menos distante.

Como vimos, por conta da natureza dos diferentes sistemas, as modificações feitas não são espelhadas de forma idêntica na pasta compartilhada no Windows. Quando acessamos um compartilhamento no Linux -- ou estamos utilizando credenciais Windows compartilhadas entre os usuários do Linux -- ou teremos erro de acesso ao compartilhamento caso aquele usuário não tenha permissão.

Já o Docker, aproveita de inovações do kernel do Linux: Namespaces, cgroups, SELinux e UnionFS para poder compartilhar sistemas completos (contêineres) para tarefas distintas com o intúito de criar **isolamento** entre os sistemas. Em cada contêiner há diversos usuários e grupos que podem nem ao menos existir no sistema hospedeiro!

Ao executar um contêiner mantido em um compartilhamento do VirtualBox você estará expostos a todas estas questões, o que inviabilizará a utilização na sua totalidade.

Sugiro que você crie um script que rode de tempos em tempos (a cada 10 minutos por exemplo) compactando e enviando os arquivos para o windows, caso realmente seja necessário fazer isso.

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cpzf /compartilhamento/arquivo.tar.gz pasta_do_conteiner
```

onde -c cria tar -p mantém permissões -z compacta -f aponta arquivo de saída

crontab -e:

```
*/10 * * * * /caminho/para/o/script.sh
```